# Changing the Column data type that exists in more than one table

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I have a column `Asset_Serial` that exists in more than one table.

The problem is that when I wanted to change its type I got something like this:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object 'PK_Assets' is dependent on column 'Asset_Serial'.
>
> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object 'FK_Assigned_Assets_Assets' is dependent on column 'Asset_Serial'.
>
> Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Asset_Serial failed because one or more objects access this column.

Any suggestions...?

Comment: check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866989/alter-table-on-dependant-column

Answer (score 1):

Asset_Serial is Primary Key of your current table and foreign key for another table 
first you should Drop your two constraint , then Alter the field in both tables and at last Create the constraints again

```
IF (OBJECT_ID('FK_ConstraintName', 'F') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
//Drop Constraint
    ALTER table [TableName] drop constraint [FK_ConstraintName]
    ALTER table [TableName] drop constraint [PK_ConstraintName]
//Alter Table Change Column
     ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN Asset_Serial
//Create Contraints
     ALTER TABLE [TableName] ADD CONSTRAINT PK_ConstraintName PRIMARY KEY (FieldName);

      ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName] 
        WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_TableName_TableName2] FOREIGN KEY([Asset_Serial])
        REFERENCES [dbo].[TableName2] ([Asset_Serial])
END
```