# Change datatype of a column and set a column as identity in SQL

Tags: sql-server, alter

```
----------------------------------------------
DepartmentCode  varchar(30) AllowNulls
----------------------------------------------
```

Does anyone know how to change the datatype of a column in SQL 2008? This is the column I want to alter but when I try this query,

```
ALTER TABLE SystemDepartment ALTER COLUMN DepartmentCode smallint NOT NULL
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The object 'PK_SystemDepartment' is dependent on column
>   'DepartmentCode'. Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1 ALTER TABLE
>   ALTER COLUMN DepartmentCode failed because one or more objects access
>   this column.

My question is how to force my query to cope with it? and I also would like to set this column as primary key and identity

Comment: To add to the responses below, first you need to get the ID of the PK. This is how I do it: SELECT name FROM sys.key_constraints WHERE type = 'PK' AND OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = N'SystemDepartment'; That returns the ID of the PK which you can then use as detailed by Hardik below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will first need to drop Primary Key constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE SystemDepartment DROP CONSTRAINT PK_SYSTEMDEPARTMENT
```

Then only you can ALTER that column.

You can not force existing column to identity. In this case you will need to add new column with identity and then do `sp_rename` to old name.

Comment: You can alter an existing column to be `IDENTITY` using [`ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084572/how-to-set-auto-increment-after-creating-a-table-without-any-data-loss/6086661#6086661) but couldn't do the datatype change from `varchar` to `int` without dropping the PK.

Answer (score 0):

If your constraint is on a user type, then don't forget to see if there is a `Default Constraint`, usually something like `DF__TableName__ColumnName__6BAEFA67`, if so then you will need to drop the Default Constraint, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP CONSTRAINT [DF__TableName__ColumnName__6BAEFA67]
```

For more info see the comments by the brilliant Aaron Bertrant on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2253852/550975).

Answer (score -1):

Try this ,

as you told you are getting primary key constraint error , 1st you have to drop the primary key and use the following query ,

```
    ALTER TABLE SystemDepartment MODIFY DepartmentCode int(3)
```

Thanks,

Venkat.

Comment: That is not valid SQL Server syntax.

Comment: am apolozige for my mistake , please try this. it will work for sure,   ALTER TABLE dbo.emp  alter column emp_id int