# unique not null and zero

Tags: sql-server, unique, alter, notnull

I am new to SQL, and I have created a unique key in a column.  Now I want to alter the column where it will not allow any null or zero values.

I tried doing this

```
ALTER TABLE sales ALTER COLUMN VerificationCode VARCHAR NOT NULL
```

However this gives the following error:

> The object 'UQ_Sales_VerificationCode' is dependent on column 'VerificationCode'.
>   Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 74
>   ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN VerificationCode failed because one or more objects access this column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first dropping the constraint *before* you alter the table column:

```
ALTER TABLE sales DROP CONSTRAINT UQ_Sales_VerificationCode
```

Then do

```
ALTER TABLE sales ALTER COLUMN VerificationCode VARCHAR NOT NULL
```

Comment: can we do this without dropping the constraint ??

Comment: Can you add the constraint back again after altering the table?  Check out [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253185/how-do-i-drop-a-column-with-object-dependencies-in-sql-server-2008) for more information.

Comment: yes your solution works but i was wondering if we can do this without dropping the constraint

Comment: I do not know of a way of doing this.