# Drop default constraint on a column in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a table with a column like this that is currently live:

```sql
name NVARCHAR(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
```

I am altering the column like this to make it nullable:

```sql
ALTER TABLE  mytable ALTER COLUMN name NVARCHAR(128) NULL
```

However, the default constraint, named 'DF__mytable__datab__7DE4B36' in one instance of the table, still remains. I know this could have been avoided if the original author named the constraint. I have several of instances of these tables but I don't want to manually delete every constraint in every table I have. What is the easiest and most elegant way of dropping this default constraint on a column in Sql Server that I can uniformily apply to every instance of this table?

### EDIT

This is the script that I ended up using:

```sql
DECLARE @table_id AS INT
DECLARE @name_column_id AS INT
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(255) 

-- Find table id
SET @table_id = OBJECT_ID('mytable')

-- Find name column id
SELECT @name_column_id = column_id
FROM sys.columns
WHERE object_id = @table_id
AND name = 'name'

-- Remove default constraint from name column
SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE mytable DROP CONSTRAINT ' + D.name
FROM sys.default_constraints AS D
WHERE D.parent_object_id = @table_id
AND D.parent_column_id = @name_column_id
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Another script that can be used to accomplish this can be found here:
[How to drop SQL default constraint without knowing its name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430456/how-to-drop-sql-default-constraint-without-knowing-its-name)

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with using most of the second answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314998/sql-server-2005-drop-column-with-constraints

Comment: Yes, that seems like that answer would work too but I haven't tested that script myself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you drop a default value or similar constraint in T-SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123060/how-do-you-drop-a-default-value-or-similar-constraint-in-t-sql)

Comment: Since you specifically refer to **default** constraints and the currently-accepted answer doesn't work for them, I suggest marking one of the answers that actually works as the correct answer instead (if that means you need to post an answer with the code from your question so you can accept, that's fine). It wastes people's time if the accept answer doesn't actually work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2005 drop column with constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314998/sql-server-2005-drop-column-with-constraints)

Answer (score 84, accepted):

This is how you would drop the constraint

```
ALTER TABLE <schema_name, sysname, dbo>.<table_name, sysname, table_name>
   DROP CONSTRAINT <default_constraint_name, sysname, default_constraint_name>
GO
```

With a script

```
-- t-sql scriptlet to drop all constraints on a table
DECLARE @database nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @table nvarchar(50)

set @database = 'dotnetnuke'
set @table = 'tabs'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(255)
WHILE EXISTS(select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS where constraint_catalog = @database and table_name = @table)
BEGIN
    select    @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @table + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    from    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
    where    constraint_catalog = @database and 
            table_name = @table
    exec    sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Credits go to Jon Galloway 
http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/04/12/442616.aspx

Comment: Modified my question a bit. I am actually looking for a way to do it without knowing the constraint name for each table I have

Comment: I've added a script that drops the constraint for a db/table

Comment: I haven't tried yet, but will the same work if I wanted to drop all default constraints for a column instead of a table. I will try modifying the script tonight to see if I can.

Comment: Unfortunately, "INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS" does not have metadata for default constraints.

Comment: I ended up using the sp_executesql proc in your answer to get the job done. See my edit on the script I used.

Comment: What good is the WHILE loop? Won't that SELECT fail if it returns more than one result?

Answer (score 9):

I would suggest:

```
DECLARE @sqlStatement nvarchar(MAX),
        @tableName nvarchar(50) = 'TripEvent',
        @columnName nvarchar(50) = 'CreatedDate';

SELECT                  
    @sqlStatement = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @tableName + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + dc.name + ';'
FROM            
    sys.default_constraints AS dc
LEFT JOIN   
    sys.columns AS sc ON (dc.parent_column_id = sc.column_id)
WHERE 
    dc.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName)
    AND type_desc = 'DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT'
    AND sc.name = @columnName

PRINT'   ['+@tableName+']:'+@@SERVERNAME+'.'+DB_NAME()+'@'+CONVERT(VarChar, GETDATE(), 127)+';  '+@sqlStatement;

IF (LEN(@sqlStatement) > 0)
     EXEC sp_executesql @sqlStatement
```

Answer (score 6):

I would like to refer a previous question, Because I have faced same problem and solved by this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430456/how-to-drop-sql-default-constraint-without-knowing-its-name).
First of all a constraint is always built with a `Hash` value in it's name. So problem is this `HASH` is varies in different Machine or Database. For example `DF__Companies__IsGlo__6AB17FE4` here `6AB17FE4` is the hash value(8 bit). So I am referring a single script which will be fruitful to all

```
DECLARE @Command NVARCHAR(MAX)
     declare @table_name nvarchar(256)
     declare @col_name nvarchar(256)
     set @table_name = N'ProcedureAlerts'
     set @col_name = N'EmailSent'

     select @Command ='Alter Table dbo.ProcedureAlerts Drop Constraint [' + ( select d.name
     from 
         sys.tables t
         join sys.default_constraints d on d.parent_object_id = t.object_id
         join sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id
                               and c.column_id = d.parent_column_id
     where 
         t.name = @table_name
         and c.name = @col_name) + ']'

    --print @Command
    exec sp_executesql @Command
```

It will drop your default constraint. However if you want to create it again you can simply try this

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProcedureAlerts] ADD DEFAULT((0)) FOR [EmailSent]
```

Finally, just simply run a `DROP` command to drop the column.

Comment: Why actually not to add it like this:

```ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProcedureAlerts] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_ProcedureAlerts_EmailSent] DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [EmailSent]
```

This way it will be named and much easier to remove next time

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer this suggestion, as it requires only the table name and column name, and clearly indicates if it succeeded or failed, with error if necessary.

```
-- Removed unnamed default constraint from column if it exists.
-- If the default constraint doesn't exist, no error is raised

DECLARE @tablename AS varchar(128) = 'optional_schema.your_table'
DECLARE @columnname AS varchar(128) = 'your_column'
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(255) = NULL

select @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + t.name + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + d.name + ';'
FROM sys.columns AS c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id AND t.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tablename) 
INNER JOIN sys.default_constraints AS D ON c.default_object_id=d.object_id
WHERE c.default_object_id IS NOT NULL
AND c.name = @columnname

--SELECT isNull(@SQL, 'NOT DEFAULTED') AS [Statement] -- Only if you want to see the statement before it runs
IF (@SQL IS NULL) 
    PRINT ' Table ' + @tablename + ', column ' + @columnname + ' does not have a default constraint.'
ELSE
    BEGIN TRY
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
        PRINT @sql + ' -- Successful'
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        PRINT @sql + ' -- Unsuccessful, Error: ' + ERROR_MESSAGE()
    END CATCH
```