# Create or change default value

Tags: sql-server, constraints, default-value

I need to create or, if it is exists, change default value for an existing column at table users.

I found how can i create/set default value for that column at this link: [How to set a default value for an existing column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791675/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-an-existing-column)

But I need a conditional statement. I mean, if a default value exists, it should be changed, if not, it should be created.

Which query do I need to execute for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can't modify a default value, the single way is to drop first the constraint:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[DF_someName]') AND type = 'D')
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[users] DROP CONSTRAINT [DF_someName]
END
```

and you create the new one :

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[users] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_someName]  DEFAULT N'NewValue' FOR [columnName]
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You determine if a default constraint exists using something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777353/drop-default-constraint-on-a-column-in-tsql) and drop it if it does. Then you add the default constraint that you need.