# How do I remove a DEFAULT constraint?

Tags: sql-server, constraints

This is what I tried. I simply want to remove the constraint I just did there

```
ALTER TABLE product
ADD DEFAULT NULL FOR sale_id

ALTER TABLE product
ALTER COLUMN sale_id DROP DEFAULT
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drop default constraint on a column in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777353/drop-default-constraint-on-a-column-in-tsql)

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME
DROP CONSTRAINT <constraint_name>
```

Eg:

```
ALTER TABLE students
ALTER COLUMN ph
DROP NOT NULL;
```